# Problem in deployment of Express app on Vercel

Tags: express, deployment, vercel, web-development-server

This is my MEVN full stack app i'm trying to deploy this on vercel but i'm not able to deploy it properly.

Repo : https://github.com/OverRevvv/ShoppingApp

feel free to checkout the repo to understand more about app but, this is what basic file tree structure looks like basically.

```
└── root
      └──/client (contains vite+vue SPA)
      └──/server
            └── src   
                └── server.js
            └──other files
            └──/dist (built vue app which is served by express app)
            └──vercel.json
```

these are the start and build command

```
  "scripts": {
    "build":"babel ./src --out-dir ./build",
    "start": "node ./build/server.js",
```

this is vercel.json file

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./build/server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/build/server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

These are vercel config and the issue i'm facing after deploying this app.[image]

[image]

what are the changes I need to do in order to deploy this app?

I expected it to deploy my server.js from the `/build'` folder that would've been generated after running build and start command to start my app. It works fine locally but I'm not able to configure it properly for vercel.